# Как Роскомнадзор может узнать на каком сервере хранятся персональные данные россиян?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, персональные-данные

Ведь насколько мне известно это технически невозможно. Роскомнадзор может лишь увидеть ip сервера с которого загружается сайт, но не узнать на каком сервере и в каком виде (может быть и в зашифрованном) хранятся персональные данные россиян.

Comment: Банально взять и запросить у вас данные может.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Так ведь данные могут хранится совершенно на другом сервере, а не на том с которого поступит ответ.

Comment: Пришлют официальный запрос - и ты сам распечатаешь все адреса-явки-пароли и им в клювике принесёшь... Против санкционированных запросов, подкреплённых нормами действующего законодательства, всякие презумпции слабо работают. Ну и оперативную работу тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Они могут непосредственно обратиться к владельцу ресурса и запросить доки о деятельности и что где находится

Comment: больная тема для тех кто хочет купить у немцев дешевые сервера

Comment: Если вы хотите нарушить закон, обмануть официальные органы и хранить данные вне РФ скрытно, я бы посоветовал для начала изучить законы и посмотреть, сколько лет тюрьмы вам светит. Сообразно этому сравните выигрыши и проигрыши от нарушения закона.

Comment: Т.е. по вашему LinkedIn предоставил нашим органам документы о том где он хранит данные россиян?

Comment: LinkedIn не предоставил, поэтому уже более двух лет в списке блокировки.